# In Unity, How do I rotate the sprite image file?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity,
I even finished taking a screenshot with my cell phone, transforming it into sprite, and storing it in a separate list variable.
But I want to save this image after rotating it 90 degrees before saving it.

Transform.rotation does not work because it is in sprite format. What should I do?

```
        byte[] bytes2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(photoname);
        Debug.Log(bytes2 + "bytes ");
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;
        texture.LoadImage(bytes2);
        Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
```

Comment: Does rotating it manually on your PC before using it as a Unity Asset not work?

Comment: Have you tried this 
https://answers.unity.com/questions/951835/rotate-the-contents-of-a-texture.html